# Django SelectMultiple fails to display saved choices

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm doing an admin form with a SelectMultiple with dynamically populated choices in Django 1.10

This is the model:

```
class HelpRequest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    groups = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

This is my form:

```
class AdminHelpRequestForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['groups'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=groups_from_ldap,
                                                     widget=SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'chosen'}))

    class Meta:
        model = HelpRequest
        fields = ('name', 'groups')
```

The form gets used in Admin:

```
@admin.register(HelpRequest)
class HelpRequestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AdminHelpRequestForm
```

The SelectMultiple saves the choices fine into the model

```
>>> ar = HelpRequest.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> print(ar.groups)
['mygroup', 'othergroup', 'yetanothergroup']
```

But will not display the saved choices from the model instance in the widget.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow counter-intuitively the solution is to add a custom clean to create a comma separated string of the choices and then splitting that string into a list and manually setting it as the initial:

```
class AdminHelpRequestForm(ModelForm):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['groups'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=groups_from_ldap,
                                              widget=SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'chosen'}))

    if self.instance:
        self.initial['groups'] = self.instance.groups.split(',')

class Meta:
    model = HelpRequest
    fields = ('name', 'groups')

def clean_groups(self):
    groups = self.cleaned_data['groups']
    if groups:
        assert isinstance(groups, (list, tuple))
        return str(','.join(groups))
    else:
    return ''
```

This has the nice benefit of making the groups rather concise and readable in the admin list view.

Another, more concise possibility is to not have that clean function at all, and just go with ast.literal_eval:

```
import ast

class AdminHelpRequestForm(ModelForm):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['groups'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=groups_from_ldap,
                                              widget=SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'chosen'}))

    if self.instance.groups:
        self.initial['groups'] = ast.literal.eval(self.instance.groups)

class Meta:
    model = HelpRequest
    fields = ('name', 'groups')
```